# Bash pressing ç or Ç emits beep instead of writing the key in PASE

Tags: terminal, ibm-midrange, vi, aix

I have a Portuguese keyboard

All keys are ok, but `ç` or `Ç` returns a beep sound instead of displaying it.

If I open vi then start typing, then `ç` or `Ç` show ok.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on AIX/PASE, the UTF-8 locales are all in the format `LL_CC` or `LL_CC.UTF-8` and *not* `ll_CC.UTF-8` like they are on Linux/BSD/etc. You want either `PT_PT` or `PT_PT.UTF-8` for UTF-8 in Portugal.

You can see the list of locales and encodings here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_72/com.ibm.aix.nlsgdrf/support_languages_locales.htm

Comment: Just to learn, how on AIX system `vi` does get able to manage correctly the keyboard without the right `locale`?

Comment: I believe it's a bug in the older version of bash we have on the platform. When I paste in a non-ASCII character like `Ç`, it moves my cursor around or just does nothing. Changing the locale doesn't seem to have any effect until you re-exec bash (though setting it in the .bash_profile seems to work).

vi and even other shells don't seem to have this problem, nor does the new version of bash we have available through yum.

Answer (score 1):

You have to fix your bash environnment for it to accept UTF-8 characters.

If you have a `.profile` or `.bash_profile`,
add to it the exact 2 following lines:

```
LANG=pt_PT.UTF-8
export LANG
```

Then open a new terminal window and check your two keys <kbd>ç</kbd> and <kbd>Ç</kbd> working correctly.

Comment: Please type the following command `echo ${LANG}` and report output.

Comment: 4.4:zeta@~> echo ${LANG}
pt_PT.UTF-8

Comment: This would normally work, but not on PASE/AIX since they use different naming conventions for their locales. Of course, since @ramstein didn't put that in the description, you couldn't have known. I knew his environment, because he linked me here from a different problem.

I've edited the title to more accurately reflect that this is specific to PASE/AIX environments.